# Read file one line at a time, then compare the grepped dates (in bash)

Tags: bash, date, while-loop, grep

I'm new to bash and the community in general so please, bear with me.

I am trying to create a simple script that:

1. Reads through txt file line by line
2. Grep specific string (in this case date) from each line and assign it to a variable
3. Compare it to another previously defined date.
4. Print the whole line if the date is bigger/smaller.

This is how i'm trying to achieve it:

```
compareDate="$(date -d '2005-01-01' '+%Y-%m-%d')"

while read -r line;
do
date="$(grep -oP 'foo \K.*')"
if [[ $date < $compareDate ]];
echo $line 
then
continue
fi
done < text.txt
```

text.txt contains:

```
foo 2000-01-01
foo 2002-01-01
foo 2004-01-01
foo 2005-01-01
foo 2006-01-01
foo 2007-01-01
foo 2008-01-01
```

The result when executed is:

```
./line.sh 
foo 2000-01-01
```

The exact problem I think is that 'date' grep defines the whole text and not one line at a time:

```
mg@mg:~/bash -x line.sh 
++ date -d 2005-01-01 +%Y-%m-%d
+ compareDate=2005-01-01
+ read -r line
++ grep -oP 'foo \K.*'
+ date='2002-01-01
2004-01-01
2005-01-01
2006-01-01
2007-01-01
2008-01-01'
+ [[ 2002-01-01
2004-01-01
2005-01-01
2006-01-01
2007-01-01
2008-01-01 < 2005-01-01 ]]
+ echo foo 2000-01-01
foo 2000-01-01
+ continue
+ read -r line
m@mg:~$
```

Also, once the 'date' is grepped and defined properly in the loop, I guess it should be converted to date format as well before comparing ?

I also tried using awk instead of grep but the end result was the same.

I've probably looked over all the similar threads regarding this and i'm not sure what i'm missing.

PS: I realize the code is most probably full of incorrect syntax and formatting, so apologies for that :)

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost close. As you have found, `grep` slurps all standard input
despite `read` tries to process it line by line.
You can instead explicitly feed the variable `$line` to `grep` with
the `here string` notation `<<< "$line"`. Please try the following:

```
compareDate="$(date -d '2005-01-01' '+%Y-%m-%d')"

while read -r line; do
    date="$(grep -oP 'foo \K.*' <<< "$line")"
    if [[ $date < $compareDate ]]; then
        echo "$line"
    fi
done < text.txt
```

Result:

```
foo 2000-01-01
foo 2002-01-01
foo 2004-01-01
```

In addition please place the line `echo "$line"` between `then` and `fi`.
Otherwise it will be invoked regardless of the `if` condition.
Hope this helps.